# Zurb Foundation 6 sticky menu in off-canvas sidebar

Tags: html, sass, sticky, zurb-foundation-6, off-canvas-menu

Hi I am trying to get zurb foundation 6 to have the off-canvas menu with sticky menu inside.
Remaked off-canvas layout to have same height of sidebars and content blocks in desktop view.

Problem:

- Sticky menu not working in right off-canvas sidebar

```html
<div class="off-canvas position-right reveal-for-medium sticky-container" id="offCanvasRight" data-off-canvas="" data-position="right" data-sticky-container="" aria-hidden="true" data-offcanvas="f9d5j6-offcanvas" style="height: 24px;">
  <div class="off-canvas position-right reveal-for-medium" id="offCanvasRight" data-off-canvas data-position="right" data-sticky-container>
    <div class="callout sticky" data-sticky data-margin-top="0">
      <h5>This is a callout.</h5>
      <p>It has an easy to override visual style, and is appropriately subdued.</p>
      <a href="#">It's dangerous to go alone, take this.</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8oq0a4t7/5/) here that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: If someone does figure this out. It world be great to get an example how to make both top bar and off canvas navigation sticky. For clarity I'm using http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/off-canvas.html#title-bar  with menu inside `<nav class="off-canvas position-left" id="offCanvasLeft" data-off-canvas data-open-method="overlap">`

Comment: You example is a bit complex. Try creating a simple page with a working off canvas menu (leave all the other components out). Once you have the working off canvas menu. Add your example menu to the off-canvas. Make sure it works. Edit your question showing your simple working off-canvas menu and ask how to make it sticky.